# Почему не получается загрузить файл из папки на сервер через UploadFile?

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Пытаюсь загрузить файл из папки TEST в корне программы на сервер

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(p, "TEST\\test.txt"));  // p - адрес загрузки
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> "{\"error\":\"empty_file\",\"error_descr\":\"empty_file\",\"error_is_logged\":false}"

Но если пытаться загрузить файл из корневой папки программы, а не из подпапки, то всё получается

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(p, "test.txt"));  // p - адрес загрузки
```

Предлагали такой вариант, но он тоже выдаёт эту ошибку

```
var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(p, @".\TEST\test.txt"));  // p - адрес загрузки
```

Пробовал подставить полный путь

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"\test\test.txt"
//или 
Application.StartupPath + @"\test\test.txt"
```

Но в случае

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Программа пытается передать файл по пути ..\name.exe\TEST\test.txt

А в случае с Application.StartupPath сделал так

```
responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(p, System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @".\TEST\test.txt"));
```

Ошибка вновь появляется.
Как быть?

Comment: Если вы используете не древний фреймворк, то используйте `System.Net.HttpClient`, так как `WebClient` считается устаревшим.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что файлы были пустые. После заполнения файла информацией - всё получилось.

Comment: Так это и есть ответ автора самому себе.